# How do you compile WebkitGTK on windows for MinGW

Tags: c++, webkit, gtk, cygwin, mingw

My experience with C++, GCC, MinGW and Cygwin is very limited. However, I already tested it and realized that Cygwin is not the ideal solution for what I am trying to do. Even though a GTK+ program with GTKWebkit works fine on Cygwin, it's not that great in terms of packaging the final project to a single .exe. The dependency on the cywin1.dll, etc... is a deal breaker.

I tested MinGW and it works flawlessly for a standard GTK only application in Windows. And the file size is great!

I tested a standard GCC compiler to compile a GTK & WebKitGtk application on Mac and it worked flawlessly.

But in the windows world where I am getting confused with GTK and WebkitGTK. What I want to do is compile a sample WebkitGTK application on Windows using MinGW. So, all the required libraries are statically linked and has a single .exe.

What are my choices? How do I actually build WebsiteGTK on Windows? Please give me the tools and as much details as you can.

FYI, QtWebkit is not going to cut it. Their licensing terms are not that commercial friendly.

Comment: Any particular reason why this [link](http://opensourcepack.blogspot.com/2011/01/building-webkitgtk-on-windows.html) wouldn't fit your needs?

Comment: Yeah, a couple of reasons. 1) It's old information and references several different versions of webkitgtk, but isn't necessarily clear on which instructions pertain to which version. 2) It reads more like shorthand notes for someone already familiar with the world of MinGW and GTK, rather than step-by-step instructions.

Answer (score 1):

I never did get WebKitGtk to compile on Windows. I think I could have got it to work using cygwin, but that's a non-starter for the project I'm working on.

I ended up using Chromium Embedded Framework instead: https://code.google.com/p/chromiumembedded/. It has clear instructions and sample apps for Mac, Linux, Windows, and mobile.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://codepasta.com/site/cpp/webkitgtk-build/) someone says that the easiest way to do that it's to cross-compile from virtual machine. Actually, there is binary there.

He uses OpenSUSE booted through VirtualBox. Then, using [osc](https://en.opensuse.org/openSUSE:OSC) tool, get the mingw32-webkitgtk from [windows:mingw:win32](http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/windows:/mingw:/win32/) and build it with osc.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @vonbrand I see. Fixed it